# Issue in understanding whats wrong with my code

Tags: java, swing, layout, paintcomponent

I have been trying to fix this error but I cant seem to figure it out whats wrong. I want to write a program that prompts the user to enter the x- and
y-positions of the center and a radius. When the user clicks a “Draw”
button, draw a circle with that center and radius in a component.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CircleMakerVeiwer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // stuff that displays that will help display the circle
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Draw Circle");

    // the obj that will be drawn
    CircleMaker circle = new CircleMaker();

    // panel is set to a flowLayout
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // panel's size is selected
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

    // now here's where the fun begins

    // labels
    JLabel x_cor = new JLabel("X Cordinate");
    JLabel y_cor = new JLabel("Y Cordinate");
    JLabel rad = new JLabel("Radius");

    // JTextFeilds
    JTextField x_input = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField y_input = new JTextField(3);
    // [in surfer dude voice] It's so RADDDD bROOOo
    JTextField rad_input = new JTextField(3);

    // all de panel adding
    panel.add(x_cor);
    panel.add(x_input);
    panel.add(y_cor);
    panel.add(y_input);
    panel.add(rad);
    panel.add(rad_input);


    // time for the action listener
    class DrawCircleListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int x, y, r;
            System.out.println("action preformed (sort of)");
            x = Integer.parseInt(x_input.getText());
            y = Integer.parseInt(y_input.getText());
            r = Integer.parseInt(rad_input.getText());

            circle.setCircle(r, x, y);

        }// end of actionPerformed

    }// end of DrawCircleListener
    DrawCircleListener listener = new DrawCircleListener();



    button.addActionListener(listener);
    panel.add(button);

    panel.add(circle);

    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setTitle("Circle Button");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

   }// end of main

}// end of CircleMakerVeiwer.java
```

I am going to be giving the CircleMaker object as well to see if anything just in case.

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;

    /*
     * This program will construct a circle it will also 
     * paint and set the parameters of the circle outside the constructor 
     */

public class CircleMaker extends JComponent {

private Ellipse2D.Double c;
    private int radius, x_cor, y_cor;

public CircleMaker() {
    c= new Ellipse2D.Double();
}

public void setCircle(int r, int x_cordinate, int y_cordinate) {
    //Graphics g;
    c = new Ellipse2D.Double(x_cordinate - r, y_cordinate - r, r * 2, r * 2);
    System.out.println("set circle was called");
    //repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.draw(c);

}


}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your error and the expected behavior? Also review [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're adding `CircleMaker` to a `JPanel` which is using `FlowLayout`, which honors the `preferredSize` of the components, but `CircleMaker`'s default `preferredSize` is `0x0`, so the component is effectively invisible
2. You don't call `repaint` when `setCircle` is called, so the component has no idea that it should be updated
3. You're violating the paint method chain contract by not calling `super.paintComponent` before doing your custom painting

Start by overriding the `getPreferredSize` method of `CircleMaker`...

```
public static class CircleMaker extends JComponent {
    //...
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
```

This will provide some idea of how big you'd like you component to be normally to the layout managers

Update the `setCircle` method to call `repaint` and add `super.paintComponent` to your `paintComponent` method

```
    public void setCircle(int r, int x_cordinate, int y_cordinate) {
        //Graphics g;
        c = new Ellipse2D.Double(x_cordinate - r, y_cordinate - r, r * 2, r * 2);
        System.out.println("set circle was called");
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(c);

    }
```

Finally, add the instance of `CircleMaker` to the `CENTER` position of the frame, which uses a `BorderLayout` by default...

```
    //panel.add(circle);

    frame.setTitle("Circle Button");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(circle);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Oh, and get rid of `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));`

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand what I was doing wrong and helped me fix it as well.

Comment: Glad it could help ;)